# How to hide code in RStudio like in Pycharm?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am working exploratively in RStudio and have quite frequently the situation that a certain part of my code should not be executed. Additionally I want to avoid that this part of my code distracts me.

In Pycharm, I can use the code folding possibilities of the IDE. By folding the code interactively (clicking on the "minus" button at the `if` statement) these things that are not needed presently are not visible anymore to me. If needed I can unfold the section and change the `if` statement accordingly.

[image: not folded]

---

[image: folded]

Is there something similar possible with RStudio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we do have similar functionality in Rstudio. As long as your code is wrapped with curly bracket `{}`, it can be folded and unfolded.

Unfolded:

[image: unfolded]

Folded (click on the little downward arrow next to the number line to fold it):

Just click on the yellow part to expand it again

[image: folded]

---

More information on the [Rstudio support page](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484568-Code-Folding-and-Sections-in-the-RStudio-IDE).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have curly brackets then just add a comment line on top, i.e.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems like OP would like to preserve the `if` statement, and only fold the content inside the `if` statement

Comment: He can add the comment lines inside the code or wherever he wants. It doesn't have to be on top and collapse the whole statement. Also a lot of functions don't have curly brackets so I think this is a more generic way of doing it